# Coordinates of cluster in CDL channel model

Tags: digital-communications, mimo, channel, multi-channel

I was reading the [3gpp specification](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_tr/138900_138999/138901/14.00.00_60/tr_138901v140000p.pdf) to understand the CDL channel models. (See section 7.7.1 and tables within).

It says that for a cluster $C$,it has angles of arrival/departure along the azimuth $(\theta)$ and zenith $(\phi)$ with respect to the transmitter/receiver. ie, $(\theta_{D,Tx}, \phi_{D,Tx}, \theta_{D,Rx}, \phi_{D,Rx})$ are known.

I am interested in calculating the co-ordinates of the cluster $C$. How can I accomplish that based on the information in the tables. For example, consider cluster 2 in Table 7.7.1-4 for CDL-D which has a normalized delay of 0.035. Also, assume Tx is at  point A $(0,0,0)$ and Rx  is at unknown point B.

Can I make use of the normalized delay and the 4 angle values to locate $C$. If not exactly, at least approximately.

**My thoughts/attempt**: In some sense, I have a triangle ABC. I can compute $\angle ACB$ based on the given 4 angles. Also, the normalized delay can be used to infer a value $k$ such that $AC +CB = AB + k.$
But, I don't know how to continue further to locate $C$.